# Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function inside of a stored procedure to create triggers automatically

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that would create triggers automatically for all the tables that exist in my Database.
I came up with the following code but I got this error when I run it: 
`Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function`

```
DELIMITER $$                                                                                                                                                                    

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procCountAllTables $$                                                                                                                                  

CREATE PROCEDURE procCountAllTables()                                                                                                                                           

BEGIN                                                                                                                                                                           
        DECLARE table_name VARCHAR(255);                                                                                                                                        
        DECLARE end_of_tables INT DEFAULT 0; 
#        DECLARE column_name VARCHAR(255);

        DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR                                                                                                                                                  
            SELECT t.table_name                                                                                                                                                 
            FROM information_schema.tables t                                                                                                                                  
            WHERE t.table_schema = DATABASE() AND t.table_type='BASE TABLE';                                                                                                    
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET end_of_tables = 1;                                                                                                           

        OPEN cur;                                                                                                                                                               

        tables_loop: LOOP                                                                                                                                                       
            FETCH cur INTO table_name;                                                                                                                                          

            IF end_of_tables = 1 THEN                                                                                                                                           
                LEAVE tables_loop;                                                                                                                                              
            END IF;                                                                                                                                                             




 #           SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT ''', table_name, ''', COUNT(*) AS Count FROM ' , table_name);                                                                               
            SET @s = CONCAT('DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS auditemployees_insert;
            CREATE TRIGGER audit',
            table_name,
            '_insert AFTER INSERT ON ',
            table_name,
            '
            FOR EACH ROW
            BEGIN
            INSERT INTO ',
            table_name,
            '_trigger (',
            GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`', column_name, '`')
                SEPARATOR ','),
            ') SELECT ',
            GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`', column_name, '`')
                SEPARATOR ','),
            ' FROM ',
            table_name,
            ' WHERE id = NEW.id;
            END$$');

            PREPARE stmt FROM @s;                                                                                                                                               
            EXECUTE stmt;                                                                                                                                                       

        END LOOP;                                                                                                                                                               

        CLOSE cur;                                                                                                                                                              
    END $$                                                                                                                                                                      

DELIMITER ;
```

Any ideas how to correct my error?

Comment: see the update to my answer (below the separator in it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo, please do try this one out, mate:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procCountAllTables $$
CREATE PROCEDURE procCountAllTables()
BEGIN                                                                                                                                                                           
    DECLARE table_name VARCHAR(255);                                                                                                                                        
    DECLARE end_of_tables INT DEFAULT 0; 
--  DECLARE column_name VARCHAR(255);

    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR                                                                                                                                                  
        SELECT t.table_name                                                                                                                                                 
        FROM information_schema.tables t                                                                                                                                  
        WHERE t.table_schema = DATABASE() AND t.table_type='BASE TABLE';                                                                                                    
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET end_of_tables = 1;                                                                                                           

    OPEN cur;                                                                                                                                                               

    tables_loop: LOOP                                                                                                                                                       
        FETCH cur INTO table_name;                                                                                                                                          

        IF end_of_tables = 1 THEN                                                                                                                                           
            LEAVE tables_loop;                                                                                                                                              
        END IF;                                                                                                                                                             

--      SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT ''', table_name, ''', COUNT(*) AS Count FROM ' , table_name);                                                                               
        SET @s = CONCAT(
            'DELIMITER $$',
            'DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS auditemployees_insert; CREATE TRIGGER audit',
            table_name,
            '_insert AFTER INSERT ON ',
            table_name,
            'FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO ',
            table_name,
            '_trigger (',
            "GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`', column_name, '`') SEPARATOR ',')",
            ') SELECT ',
            "GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`', column_name, '`') SEPARATOR ',')",
            ' FROM ',
            table_name,
            "WHERE id = NEW.id;"
            "END$$"
        );

        PREPARE stmt FROM @s;                                                                                                                                               
        EXECUTE stmt;                                                                                                                                                       
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;                                                                                                                                                              
END $$                                                                                                                                                                      
DELIMITER ;
```

**Notes:**

- This type/style of implementation is not really recommended, especially if you will put this into a `production` level of environment
- This will `provide` output/expected outcome but can `sacrifice` maintainability due to `improper` implementation
- I like the `idea` of making a trigger through a stored procedure, but somehow I am `against` it
- The only error I can see is the proper usage of `'` and `"`
- Proper indentation helps, trust me
- And the `commented` line(s), you know what to do with those

Anyway, cheers

Comment: I don't think you can be sure all his tables have columns named `column_name`...;) But I agree with your notes, not a good practice for field/production operations, but I could see it as a semi-decent way to create "stub" triggers during development (if you have boiler plate code you wanted to be in all). It looks like they are intending this for a "history table" scenario.

Comment: supposedly, I think it's a temporary `variable` name so he/she can post his/her code here in SO, then he'll adjust into his/her `real` code.. maybe. Yeah mate, agreed, cheers

Comment: Yeah, it's a local variable in their code, but not within the trigger (which is where your answer is putting it, and actually the whole group_concat).

Comment: Thank you for your help @Avidos  I was wondering if you got this error by any chance? `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS auditemployees_insert; CREATE TRIGGER auditde' at line 1` I think the problem is the delimiter but Im not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a query and then trying to fit it into the construction of the trigger code string. For each table, you need to

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('`', column_name, '`') SEPARATOR ',') INTO @columnsList FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = [the current table name]
;
```

You could also just join to `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` (on `table_schema` and `table_name`) in your cursor query, and have two fields; `table_name` and `columns_list`.

Edit: Also, I am not sure how much prepared statements accept multiple statements; so you may want to prepare and execute the preliminary `DROP` of each trigger separately from it's (re)creation.

Also:

- I am not sure what purpose you had in mind for the COUNT query.
- You may want to filter table names ending in `_trigger` from your cursor.

---

Edit: Something like this... *(untested, so I might have typos or other similar oversights)*

```
DELIMITER $$                                                                                                                                                                    

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS procCountAllTables $$                                                                                                                                  

CREATE PROCEDURE procCountAllTables()

BEGIN
        DECLARE table_name VARCHAR(255);
        DECLARE trigger_name VARCHAR(255);
        DECLARE target_tablename VARCHAR(255);
        DECLARE end_of_tables INT DEFAULT 0; 
        DECLARE column_names VARCHAR(1024);
        -- Be aware of GROUP_CONCAT's configured length limitation

        DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
            SELECT t.table_name
               , GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("`",c.column_name,"`")) AS column_names
            FROM information_schema.tables AS t
               INNER JOIN information_schema.columns AS c
               USING (table_schema, table_name)
            WHERE t.table_schema = DATABASE() AND t.table_type='BASE TABLE'
            GROUP BY t.table_name
            ;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET end_of_tables = 1;

        OPEN cur;

        tables_loop: LOOP
            FETCH cur INTO table_name, column_names;
            IF end_of_tables = 1 THEN
                LEAVE tables_loop;
            END IF;

            SET target_tablename := CONCAT(table_name, '_trigger');
            SET trigger_name := CONCAT('audit', table_name, '_insert');

            SET @s := CONCAT("DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `", trigger_name, "`;");
            PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
            EXECUTE stmt;

            SET @s := CONCAT(
               "CREATE TRIGGER `", trigger_name, "` "
               "AFTER INSERT ON `", table_name, "` "
               "FOR EACH ROW "
               "INSERT INTO `", target_tablename, "` (", column_names, ") "
               "SELECT ", column_names, " "
               "FROM `", table_name, "` "
               "WHERE id = NEW.id "
               ";"
            ;    
            PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
            EXECUTE stmt;                                                                                                                                                       

        END LOOP;                                                                                                                                                               

        CLOSE cur;                                                                                                                                                              
    END $$                                                                                                                                                                      

DELIMITER ;
```

Note that I've removed the `BEGIN` and `END` from the trigger definition. Since the trigger itself executes only a single statement, I think they are not necessary; and in my limited experience with these specific kinds of tasks, a delimiter override (which was not actually done on the prepare statement) tends to confuse prepared statements.

Also, you can probably get away without even using a select in the trigger if the cursor is changed like so:

```
SELECT t.table_name
, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("`", column_name, "`")) AS column_names
, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("NEW.`", column_name, "`")) AS source_list
...
```

and the trigger insert changed like so:

```
...
"INSERT INTO `", target_tablename, "` (", column_names, ") "
"VALUES (", source_list, ") "
";"
```

*of course, you'll need to fetch the source_list from the cursor into a source_list local variable.*